# How to add custom directives for Input type in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I want to create an Input type which takes some inputs (from authenticated as well as non-authenticated users). I want to be able to restrict some input fields based on the authentication.

But I am aware that there is no resolve method for input types. So how do I achieve this?

```
Input UserInput {
  data: String!
  shareWith: [ID!] @auth(requires: USER)
}
```

Can someone please help me if it is possible to make a directive which can work with input types?

Comment: no need to define it at type level - check role in resolver and throw error when not available

Comment: Is that really how I should proceed? Wouldn't it look messy?

Comment: This is an `input`, something that'd come from the `caller`, so I am not sure why you're trying to require `auth` for `shareWith`. It's not like this is going to return some data that's only available to authorized users.

Comment: @goto1 actually it is. I am not that well aware with design ideas so I may be wrong, but this is a common field for all the users, wherein only the registered users may add a share with field.

Comment: No, the `input type` is not responsible for defining what to return to the user - that's the job of your `resolver`, therefore you should check in your resolver if the user is authorized and **only then** return the data that's being requested. Make `shareWith` optional and only process it if user is authorized. Similar to what's happening over here - https://typegraphql.ml/docs/0.16.0/authorization.html